# If Kurama is the living embodiment of hatred, then what about the other Tailed Beasts?

Tags: naruto

If Kurama is really the living embodiment of hatred (not some self proclaim title), then what about the other Tailed Beasts? Are they the embodiment of something else?

Comment: Who said that he was the embodiment of hatred? I've read the wiki but I can't find anywhere that says that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [naruto.wikia.com](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kurama#Personality)

> Long years of receiving humanity's negative treatment caused Kurama to
>   develop intense hostility and distrust against them, even going as far
>   as proclaiming itself to be the living embodiment of hatred.

So, he was not embodiment of hatred by itself from start but became like this later on. So its not a tailed beast characteristic to represent as embodiment of single emotion per tailed beast.

Comment: This is what i also thought to be true. Not only with kurama but also shukaku who is related to the fear in Gaara ... hmm